# How to determine nginx/HTTPS encryption is my bottleneck?

Tags: nginx, performance

I'm using a Digital Ocean droplet (like an EC2 host), it's Ubuntu 22.10, and running a node.js application. However, and this may be a bad idea, I'm running nginx on the same host and the application and it's terminating the HTTPS connection. It all works mostly fine, with a caveat.

My most expensive call takes about 622 ms to compute the results but then takes about 6 seconds to send the data. As the slowdown is on sending the response, I suspect the encryption for HTTPS on this anemic droplet is the bottleneck.

The question I have is, how do I gather data on nginx performance to determine if that is the bottleneck? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much data are you sending? Which cipher are you using for TLS? What CPU load does the system report? The only CPU-intensive part (the key exchange and RSA/EC signatures) has already been done when you established the connection – when the response is being sent, all that's left is AES-GCM or similar, and you can measure AES-GCM throughput using various tools. For a reasonable amount of data I'd be _highly_ surprised if it was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of the encryption can be tested by the `openssl speed` tool (see [man openssl-speed](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-speed.html)):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> openssl speed [-help] [-engine id] [-elapsed] [-evp algo] [-decrypt] [-rand file...] [-writerand file] [-primes num] [-seconds num] [-bytes num] [algorithm...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This command is used to test the performance of cryptographic algorithms. To see the list of supported algorithms, use the list --digest-commands or list --cipher-commands command. The global CSPRNG is denoted by the rand algorithm name.

For example, this is run on the Debian 11 desktop with i5-4570 CPU (released 10 years ago):

```
$ openssl speed aes
Doing aes-128 cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 42126692 aes-128 cbc's in 3.00s
...
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 16384 size blocks: 31677 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
built on: Fri May 26 21:30:44 2023 UTC
options:bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) aes(partial) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/openssl-FSeIwm/openssl-1.1.1n=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes  16384 bytes
aes-128 cbc     224675.69k   234114.05k   234762.07k   236847.45k   236888.06k   237076.48k
aes-192 cbc     194343.19k   199041.24k   199621.38k   200813.57k   200278.02k   196515.16k
aes-256 cbc     167304.09k   171438.21k   172737.84k   172836.18k   172886.70k   172998.66k
```

Each core is able to encrypt 170 MB/sec with AES-256-CBC *without HW acceleration*. As it is 2-core 4-thread CPU, I'd also run a 4-thread test (`openssl -multi 4 aes`), and got 642MB/s overall.

It's possible to test AES-128-GCM with "EVP" interface:

```
$ openssl speed -multi 4 -evp aes-128-gcm
...
evp            1467308.76k  3688563.14k  7856414.29k 10757336.06k 12390427.31k 12442206.21k
```

This shows 12 GB/s using AES-NI hardware acceleration.

So even if your server was to run on this computer, encryption wouldn't be the bottleneck.